# Sqoop export for 100 million records faster

Tags: hadoop, export, teradata, sqoop

I have query similar to the below

```
sqoop export 
    --connect jdbc:teradata://server/database=BIGDATA 
    --username dbuser 
    --password dbpw 
    -Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=500
    --batch 
    --hive-table country
    --table COUNTRY
    --input-null-non-string '\\N' \ --input-null-string '\\N'
```

The above query is working fine for 3 million records(Takes 1 hour to load the data to TeraData table). For 100 million records to export the data to Teradata empty table i think it may take more time to complete the export.  How can i efficiently write the query to export the data faster without failing the query?

Comment: @JamesZ  I didnt understand what you mean here but i changed the wording.

Comment: What does the Teradata table look like? (Primary index definition with respect to skew) Can you load a staging table defined as a No Primary Index table first? Have you ruled out the network as a limiting factor? Is sqoop using enough worker tasks to maximize parallel efficiency?

Comment: The teradata table is multiload (something like that, i dont remember the exact type but its a simple table which takes the first column as primary key). I havent defined any limiting factor and its no primary key has been defined. yes, the sqoop job has enough resource but would need to configure to best perform without failing because of more parallel tasks and run faster than time being consumed. @RobPaller

Comment: @RobPaller If you could provide/update the query with optimizing would give me more clarity.

Comment: I mean using "lakh", which I removed already.

Comment: @JamesZ ok. Should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider increasing your `--fetch-size` (the number of entries that sqoop has to fetch per scoop of data) from the default `1000` to `e.g` `--fetch-size 10000 0r 20000` depending on your available memory as well as your environments' bandwidth.

Comment: Is it possible to use fetch-size along with the parameters  "-Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=500" and     "--batch" which already runs as batch and records configurable and used now as 500.

Comment: i was also trying hadoop teradata connector which is erroring out on timestamp, so setting this property might work<br><property> 
<name>tdch.input.timestamp.format</name> 
<value>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</value> 
<description>Port that this metastore should listen on. 
</description> 
</property>

Comment: May be i am trying the use the below connector <br> hadoop jar $TDCH_JAR com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConnectorExportTool -url jdbc:teradata://1.1.1.1/DATABASE=test_db -username user123 -password pwd123 -jobtype hdfs -fileformat textfile -method internal.fastload -separator "\u0001" -sourcepaths /apps/hive/wareho -targettable td_tab1 -nummappers 5 but i still see some issue as index out of bound exception